# javascript regExp works with testers but not in my site

Tags: javascript, regex

Simple RegExp to test for mm/yyyy works on all online RegExp testers but not on my site.

```
var re=new RegExp("^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)$");
if(!re.test(theForm.ceDate.value)) alert("Date must be MM/YYYY");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried substituting `theForm.ceDate.value` with a literal for testing?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens?

Comment: If a regular expression takes too much energy to craft, and if it's too hard to read, you might be better off using something else. Why not just `.split("/")` and check each token individually?

Answer (score 4):

Your string literal is swallowing the `\` escapes.

Instead, you should use a regex literal: `/(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)$/`

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript

```
function Validation() {
    debugger;
    var reg = new RegExp('^(0[1-9]|1(1|2)|[0-9])\\/(20[0-9]{2}|19[0-9]{2})$');
    var txt = document.getElementById('<%= txt.ClientID %>');
    if (txt.value.match(reg) != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

---

### Mark Up

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSubmit" Text="Submit" 
                                 OnClientClick="return Validation();" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```